# How to change div into a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I turn a DIV into an input button?

This works great for a checkbox to turn it into a type text:

```
$('#mycheckbox').get(0).type = 'text';
```

But that doesn't work, nothing happens:

```
$('#mydiv').get(0).type = 'button'; //formatting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replaceWith` for div.

```js
$("#mydiv").replaceWith("<input type='button' value='MyButton'>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works all fine! Now I just need to figure out how to attach an onclick event handler to that button

Comment: See this old and epic question how dynamic added dom work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Thanks, works all fine like this: $("#nuBreadcrumb0").replaceWith("<input type='button' id= 'nuBreadcrumb0' value='MyButton0'>")
$("#nuBreadcrumb0").click(function(){  alert('click!');});

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change div to button.

You can turn checkbox to text because you change `<input type="checkbox">` to `<input type="text">`. But There's no `<div type="button">` in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can't change a tagName, but you could change it to a submit

```
$('#mydiv').get(0).type = 'submit';
```

better

```
$('#mydiv').attr('type','submit'); // jQuery
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! However, this code shows no effect.

Comment: on an input tag ?

Answer (score 0):

this will loop through all buttons in the page and change it them into div's

```
    var Btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    
    Btns.forEach(changeNodeName)
  
    function changeNodeName(el){
        console.log(el)
        var elNodeName = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        var newString = el.outerHTML.trim()
        .replace('<'+ elNodeName,'<div');
    
        // To replace the end tag, we can't simply use replace()
        // which means if our element has a child element with the
        // same node name the end tag of the *child element* will be 
        // replaced, not the parent element. So,
        
        newString = newString
        .slice(0,newString.lastIndexOf('</div>'));    
        //now newString = "<div id='element'>Text" 'without closing tag'
        
        newString = newString + "</div>";
        el.outerHTML = newString;
        
        // because, replace() will replace the first occurrence,
    }
```